# Multi Column Combo in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, client-side

I am new to Ext Js Framework. Can any one Tell me Is there any Multi column Combo Exist in this Framework. 
I want a Combo box Which Displays More than One Columns When User Clicks on it.

Any Help Will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'tpl' : 
The template string, or Ext.XTemplate instance to use to display each item in the dropdown list

check [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?7749-Adding-a-MultiColumn-ComboBox-....)

Comment: That solution worked great. How do you get that same template look to show up as your displayValue once the selection has been made?

Answer (score 1):

In this you need to use the displayTpl

```
tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
  '<tpl for=".">',
    '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{firstName} {lastName} {email}</div>',
  '</tpl>'
),
displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
  '<tpl for=".">',
    'firstName} {lastName} {email}',
  '</tpl>'
)
```